# How to authorize user to access to resource based on OR rules

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, authorization, asp.net-core-2.0

### Scenario:

I have complex WebApi application. In controllers I want to authorize user to access specified resource based on following business rule:

In order to access a resource, User must

- be **Authenticated**

AND

- be **Author** of the resource OR be **Sponsor** of the resource OR be in Admin role

AND 
- other rules based on type of resource and action

### Question:

How to organize and configure Policies, Requirements and RequirementHandlers to meet this rule (with OR conditions)?

I know the authorization API was designed so that it can handle any scenario, but I need strategy so that it is maintainable and readable in complex and evolving scenarios.

---

#### Here is my initial attempt:

- I have created `IsAuthorRequirement` and generic handler, that can handle this requirement for all resources.
- I have `IsSponsorRequirement` and multiple handlers, since each resource type has to be handled differently.

My initial thoughts were create custom policy for each Resource and Action, e.g.:

- CanReadResource1Policy
- CanEditResouce1Policy
- CanReadResouce2Policy
- CanEditResource2Policy

In other words, policy per permission.

```
public async Task<ActionResult> GetById(int id)
{
   var resource = _dbContext.Resources1.Find(id);

   var authResult = await _authorizationService.AuthorizeAsync(User, resource, Policies.CanReadResouce1);
   if (!authResult.Succeeded) return Forbid();
}
```

But now I feel I'm somewhat fighting the framework and I that misused policies/requirement. For example, by default policy requires all requirements to succeed, but my business rules has OR condition. I know multiple requirement handlers creates de facto OR condition, but should I use this to create the OR condition in my buseness rule?

Comment: I think you are on the right track. Even the documentation says `In cases where you want evaluation to be on an OR basis you implement multiple handlers for a single requirement` (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authorization/policies), also check out the docs on resource based authorization (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authorization/resourcebased?tabs=aspnetcore2x)

Comment: @MuqeetKhan: I know, but what would be the requirement?